# extracting datatframe and count values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, count

I have this data, save it in dataframe

```
data = {'Eventname': ['100m','200m','Discus','100m','200m','Discus'],
        'Year': [2030,2030,2031,2030,2031,2032],
       'FirstPlace': ['John Smith', 'Shar jean', 'Abi whi', 'mik jon','joh doe', 'John Smith'],
        'SecPlace': ['joh doe', 'John Smith', 'Shar jean', 'Hen Hun','Tom Will', 'Gord Jay'],
        'thiPlace': ['mik jon', 'Lisa tru', 'John Smith', 'Bret Tun','Tim Smith', 'Jack Mann'] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new dataframe, the 1st coulmn should contain the name of all people occurd in [first place], [secondplace], [thirdplace] columns without duplications. And then count how many times each name happend in each column
I wrote this code,

```
NewArr=pd.DataFrame()
NewArr['first']=df['FirstPlace'].value_counts()
NewArr['second']=df['SecPlace'].value_counts()
NewArr['third']=df['thiPlace'].value_counts()
```

The code has these problems:

1. it only shows me the first 5 names from the [firstplace]
2. I want the value (0) not a Nan in the result
3. I want to add the coulmn title "AthleteName" above the names

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['FirstPlace', 'SecPlace', 'thiPlace'])
pd.crosstab(df1.value, df1.variable).reset_index(
    names='Names').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         Names  FirstPlace  SecPlace  thiPlace
0      Abi whi           1         0         0
1     Bret Tun           0         0         1
2     Gord Jay           0         1         0
3      Hen Hun           0         1         0
4    Jack Mann           0         0         1
5   John Smith           2         1         1
6     Lisa tru           0         0         1
7    Shar jean           1         1         0
8    Tim Smith           0         0         1
9     Tom Will           0         1         0
10     joh doe           1         1         0
11     mik jon           1         0         1
```

Comment: Thank you very much..
As I want to create a new dataframe .. I change it to 
'df2=pd.crosstab(df1.value, df1.variable)'

Comment: but how to save the people names also in another column? the names are not saved inside a the dataframe as a separate coulmn ?

Comment: Please, @almegdadi, see my updated solution.

Comment: show me this error

TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Comment: According to [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), the parameter `names` is new! Therefore, you need to update your pandas installation, @almegdadi!